# How do I remove old data from a Glue Studio ETL job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a CSV file in an S3 bucket. I am using Glue Studio to take that CSV and create various partitions in an S3 bucket so that I can speed up my Athena queries.

However, when the job runs, it's creating new files in the partitions and it retains the previous data.
Is there a way to remove the data from the glue job's previous run before adding the new partitioned data?

Answer (score 1):

you can add this line to your script to purge your s3 bucket

```
glueContext.purge_s3_path("s3://my_bucket/path_to_purge/", options={"retentionPeriod": 0}, transformation_ctx="")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the visual editor on Glue you can leverage AWS EventBridge Scheduler, that way you can coordinate S3 actions (for example) and tie them to events within Glue or external ones.

AWS EventBridge Scheduler: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html